# Contstruct $Q$ such as $Q^*A-DQ^* =R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $D=\mathrm{diag}\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}$ be $n\times n$ hermitian matrices. Construct unitary matrix $Q$ such as $Q^* A - DQ^* = R$, where $R$ is upper triangular.

Here $Q^*$ is conjugate transpose.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that this is a linear system of equations that can be solved for $Q$.  Are we to suppose that $R$ is a **given** upper triangular matrix, or is it sufficient to choose a $Q$ that makes $Q^*A - DQ^*$ upper triangular?

Comment: More specifically, this seems to be a particular form of a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: If $R$ is fixed, then the possibility of solution depends on whether $A$ and $D$ have a common eigenvalue.

Comment: If $R$ is not fixed, then we can take $R = 0$ whenever $A$ and $D$ have a common eigenvalue.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom R is not given and yes  it is sufficient to construct the matrix Q. I was trying to construct such Q by QR-decomposition.Unfortunately neither with the Gram-Schmid method nor Householder matrix I got results.

Comment: Does $Q$ need to be invertible?  Unitary?  I suppose that $Q = 0$ won't work for your purposes.

Comment: yes, forgot to include that Q must be unitary.